# How to use jinja2 and its i18n extension (using babel) outside flask

Tags: python, jinja2, python-babel

How can I use jinja2 with babel outside a flask application.
Supposing that I have locale dir which is populated using pybabel command. I want to load translation files and translate my template files.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found the solution. Here's how you can use jinja2/babel without flask integration.

### Preconditions

Preconditions are described just to complete the example, all of them can have other values or names.

You use message domain named "html" for messages (domain is arbitrary name, default is "message").

There is a directory "i18n" with translated and compiled messages (e.g. with a file `i18n/cs/LC_MESSAGES/html.mo`).

You prefer to render your templates using "cs" or "en" locale.

The templates are located in directory `templates` and there exists a jinja2 template named `stack.html` there, so there exists a file `templates/stack.html`.

### Code sample

```
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
from babel.support import Translations

locale_dir = "i18n"
msgdomain = "html"
list_of_desired_locales = ["cs", "en"]
loader = FileSystemLoader("templates")
extensions = ['jinja2.ext.i18n', 'jinja2.ext.autoescape', 'jinja2.ext.with_']

translations = Translations.load(locale_dir, list_of_desired_locales)
env = Environment(extensions=extensions, loader=loader) # add any other env options if needed
env.install_gettext_translations(translations)

template = env.get_template("stack.html")
rendered_template = template.render()
```

The `rendered_template` contains the rendered HTML content now, probably in "cs" locale.

Comment: but how do you control the language? I was expecting to be able to pass something like `template.render(locale='en')`

Answer (score 3):

This works great! Thanks.

I. jinja2 dependency MarkupSafe

II. Python babel dependency ytz

See for these steps at http://tlphoto.googlecode.com/git/jinja2_i18n_howto.txt

1. Create the folder structure (no whitespace after the commas!!!)

   `mkdir -pv ./lang/{en_US,zh_CN,fa_IR,es_VE,de_DE,ja_JP}/LC_MESSAGES/`
2. Extract

   `pybabel -v extract -F babel.config -o ./lang/messages.pot ./`
3. Init/Update

   3.1 Init

   `pybabel init -l zh_CN -d ./lang -i ./lang/messages.pot`

   3.2 Update

   `pybabel update -l zh_CN -d ./lang -i ./lang/messages.pot`
4. Compile

   `pybabel compile -f -d ./lang`

Comment: The link is now out-dated. And I wonder if it is still working if I use it from `web.archive.org` ? And how do I create the `messages.pot` file?